# A single noun for a written article intended to persuade the reader to a particular political purpose?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I know I've encountered this word before. Examples include almost every editorial and op-ed article.

It's not necessarily *written*, and it could be a speech.

The article doesn't necessarily *persuade* the audience, but the writer intends to persuade. It's more respectable and compelling than a *screed*. It doesn't have the pejorative shadings of *propaganda*, nor the semi-seriousness of *public relations*, nor the lofty pretension sometimes associated with *eloquence* and *rhetoric*, nor the aggressiveness of *argument*, nor the passionlessness of *opinion*.

Comment: Do you mean that the author doesn't come right out and state that they are shilling for a particular political entity, but that is how an astute person would read it? A [tract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tract_(literature))?

Comment: Opinion piece.  Blurb.

Comment: The unqualified term wouldn't presume intentional deception.

Answer (score 1):

A **polemic** is a a fiery proposition or editorial:

... an argument or controversy, especially over a doctrine or belief

[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/polemic)

Answer (score 0):

A [**position paper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_paper).

> A position paper is an essay that presents an opinion about an issue –
>   typically that of the author or some specified entity. Position papers
>   are published in academia, in politics, in law and other domains. A
>   position paper presents an arguable opinion about an issue. The goal
>   of a position paper is to convince the audience that your opinion is
>   valid and worth listening to. Ideas that you are considering need to
>   be carefully examined in choosing a topic, developing your argument,
>   and organizing your paper.
>
> Position papers range from the simplest format of a letter to the
>   editor through to the most complex in the form of an academic position
>   paper.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_paper) Position papers are also used by large organizations to make
>   public the official beliefs and recommendations of the group.